# Calculus 3 integration question

Tags: calculus, integration

Hi I'm a bit stuck with an exam paper question I don't really know how to begin this question.

$$\ \vec F (x, y, z) = 2y \vec i + x \vec j + z \vec k , x, y, z ∈ R. $$

Let $\ Γ_1$ denote the path $\ x = z = y^2 $
from (0, 0, 0) to (1, 1, 1).

Let $\ Γ_2$ denote the
line segment from (1, 1, 1) to (2, 3, 4). Evaluate
$$\ \int_{Γ1∪Γ2} ( \vec F \cdot \vec dr) $$

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You haven't defined the vector field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can begin finding a parametrization for $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$. Such as:
\begin{align*}
\Gamma_1:&&(x,y,z)&=(t^2,t,t^2),&\; 0\le t\le 1\\
\Gamma_2:&&(x,y,z)&=(t,2t-1,3t-2),&\; 1\le t\le 2
\end{align*}

---

Now, you can break the integral into two integrals:
\begin{align*}
\int_{Γ1∪Γ2} ( \vec F \cdot \vec dr)&=\int_{\Gamma_1} \vec{F}\cdot dr +\int_{\Gamma_2} \vec{F}\cdot dr 
\end{align*}
Where
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Gamma_1} \vec{F}\cdot dr&=\underbrace{\int_{0\le t\le 1}(2t\hat{\mathbf{i}}+t^2\hat{\mathbf{j}}+t^2\hat{\mathbf{k}})\cdot(dx\hat{\mathbf{i}}+dy\hat{\mathbf{j}}+dz\hat{\mathbf{k}})}_{\text{Here we sustitute }x,y,z\text{ given in the parametrization of }\Gamma_1}\\[10pt]
&=\int_0^1 (2t\hat{\mathbf{i}}+t^2\hat{\mathbf{j}}+t^2\hat{\mathbf{k}})\cdot\overbrace{(2t\hat{\mathbf{i}}+\hat{\mathbf{j}}+2t\hat{\mathbf{k}})dt}^{dx=2tdt,\;\;dy=dt\;\;dz=2tdt}\\
&=\int_0^1(4t^2+t^2+2t^3)dt\\[3pt]
&=\int_0^1(5t^2+2t^3)dt\\[3pt]
&=\left. \frac53t^3+\frac12t^4\right|_0^1\\[2pt]
&=\frac{13}6
\end{align*}
The another integral can be computed in a similar way.

Comment: Hi would you be able to explain where you got $\ Γ_2 $ from?

Comment: @LaurenBurke An equation for a straight line which pass for $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ parallel to a vector $\vec{\mathbf{v}}=(a,b,c)$ is
$$\vec{\mathbf{r}}(t)=(x,y,z)=(x_0+at,y_0+bt,z_0+ct)$$
In this problem we have $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(1,1,1)$ and $\vec{\mathbf{v}}=(a,b,c)=(2-1,3-1,4-1)=(1,2,3)$. Also in order to have $\vec{\mathbf{r}}(1)=(1,1,1)$ and $\vec{\mathbf{v}}(2)=(2,3,4)$ I took the parameter $t-1$ instead $t$. Thus
$$\vec{\mathbf{r}}(t)=(x,y,z)=(1+1(t-1),1+2(t-1),1+3(t-1))=(t,2t-1,3t-2)$$

Comment: Brilliant! Sorry to be a pain (I'm quite new to this area as you can tell). Is there anyway you could give me steps in how to get my answer? I'm not asking you to do the question just sort of an outline or format I could follow?

Comment: With that parametrization, t moves continuously through the x, y, and z values you want. So just take the integral from $t=(0,2)$.

Comment: @LaurenBurke You are welcome.